# Inline list of tags in HTML email

Tags: html-email

I'm trying to create an HTML newsletter template that will show a list of tags at some point in that email. The number of elements of that list is dynamic. Instead of having a comma/space-separated list, I would like to style those tags with a border around each of the tags, for example.

Formatting as a table will probably not work, because generating one  for each tag will create a table too wide to display properly within its parent table. On the other hand, generating one  will not result in an inline list.

I thought of either doing it using  with their css set to display:inline; or a  set to display:inline; as well:

```
<span class="hashtag-span">#hashtag</span>
<span class="hashtag-span">#anotherone</span>
```

or alternatively

```
<ul class="hashtag-list">
    <li>#hashtag</li>
    <li>#anotherone</li>
</ul>
```

Probably the trickiest part: this has to be Outlook-compatible :(

You can see what I'd like to achive in my jsfiddle:
http://jsfiddle.net/wo64xLnf/3/

Thanks for your help, crowd!

Comment: conventional html does not work, you need to use tables for Email Template..

Comment: i know about tables and all the rest of the email template is set up with tables, but how to set up that list of tags in a format displayed inline? the list of tags is unknown. the emails are being generated by a database/server-side. i cannot just insert a table with n <td> elements or n <tr> elements.

my question is how to format the html/css for that list to display properly  (i.e. inline) in an email.

Answer (score 1):

This is not an easy task at all and requires quite a bit of reiterate code.  Your best bet is to use MSO conditional with tables to make it work for Outlook and divs with display:inline-block for most other clients. Span tags as objects has very spotty support in many clients, span is best used just for styling fonts in HTML email.

See below for programmatic HTML block:

```
 <!--[if ( gte mso 9) | (IE)]><table align="left"><tr><td align="center" valign="top" style="padding: 0 4px 5px 0;"><![endif]-->
<div style="display: inline-block; vertical-align: top; margin: 0 4px 5px 0;">
    <table bgcolor="#eaeaea" valign="top" align="center" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" border="0" style="border-collapse:collapse; background: #eaeaea;">
        <tr>
            <td align="center" bgcolor="#eaeaea" style="padding: 3px 5px 3px 3px; font-size: 12px; border: #666666 1px solid;">#hashtag</td>
        </tr>
    </table>
</div>
<!--[if (mso) | (IE)]></td></tr></table><![endif]-->
```

And this is a full version using your HTML from the fiddle:

```
<!doctype html>
<html>
<head>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<title>Untitled Document</title>
</head>

<body>
  <!--[if ( gte mso 9) | (IE)]><table align="left"><tr><td align="center" valign="top" style="padding: 0 4px 5px 0;"><![endif]-->
<div style="display: inline-block; vertical-align: top; margin: 0 4px 5px 0;">
    <table bgcolor="#eaeaea" valign="top" align="center" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" border="0" style="border-collapse:collapse; background: #eaeaea;">
        <tr>
            <td align="center" bgcolor="#eaeaea" style="padding: 3px 5px 3px 3px; font-size: 12px; border: #666666 1px solid;">#hashtag</td>
        </tr>
    </table>
</div>
<!--[if (mso) | (IE)]></td></tr></table><![endif]-->
  <!--[if ( gte mso 9) | (IE)]><table align="left"><tr><td align="center" valign="top" style="padding: 0 4px 5px 0;"><![endif]-->
<div style="display: inline-block; vertical-align: top; margin: 0 4px 5px 0;">
    <table bgcolor="#eaeaea" valign="top" align="center" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" border="0" style="border-collapse:collapse; background: #eaeaea;">
        <tr>
            <td align="center" bgcolor="#eaeaea" style="padding: 3px 5px 3px 3px; font-size: 12px; border: #666666 1px solid;">#anotherone</td>
        </tr>
    </table>
</div>
<!--[if (mso) | (IE)]></td></tr></table><![endif]-->
  <!--[if ( gte mso 9) | (IE)]><table align="left"><tr><td align="center" valign="top" style="padding: 0 4px 5px 0;"><![endif]-->
<div style="display: inline-block; vertical-align: top; margin: 0 4px 5px 0;">
    <table bgcolor="#eaeaea" valign="top" align="center" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" border="0" style="border-collapse:collapse; background: #eaeaea;">
        <tr>
            <td align="center" bgcolor="#eaeaea" style="padding: 3px 5px 3px 3px; font-size: 12px; border: #666666 1px solid;">#anotherAwesomeHashtag</td>
        </tr>
    </table>
</div>
<!--[if (mso) | (IE)]></td></tr></table><![endif]-->
  <!--[if ( gte mso 9) | (IE)]><table align="left"><tr><td align="center" valign="top" style="padding: 0 4px 5px 0;"><![endif]-->
<div style="display: inline-block; vertical-align: top; margin: 0 4px 5px 0;">
    <table bgcolor="#eaeaea" valign="top" align="center" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" border="0" style="border-collapse:collapse; background: #eaeaea;">
        <tr>
            <td align="center" bgcolor="#eaeaea" style="padding: 3px 5px 3px 3px; font-size: 12px; border: #666666 1px solid;">#thiswillgoviral</td>
        </tr>
    </table>
</div>
<!--[if (mso) | (IE)]></td></tr></table><![endif]-->
  <!--[if ( gte mso 9) | (IE)]><table align="left"><tr><td align="center" valign="top" style="padding: 0 4px 5px 0;"><![endif]-->
<div style="display: inline-block; vertical-align: top; margin: 0 4px 5px 0;">
    <table bgcolor="#eaeaea" valign="top" align="center" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" border="0" style="border-collapse:collapse; background: #eaeaea;">
        <tr>
            <td align="center" bgcolor="#eaeaea" style="padding: 3px 5px 3px 3px; font-size: 12px; border: #666666 1px solid;">#hashtagcraziness</td>
        </tr>
    </table>
</div>
<!--[if (mso) | (IE)]></td></tr></table><![endif]-->
  <!--[if ( gte mso 9) | (IE)]><table align="left"><tr><td align="center" valign="top" style="padding: 0 4px 5px 0;"><![endif]-->
<div style="display: inline-block; vertical-align: top; margin: 0 4px 5px 0;">
    <table bgcolor="#eaeaea" valign="top" align="center" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" border="0" style="border-collapse:collapse; background: #eaeaea;">
        <tr>
            <td align="center" bgcolor="#eaeaea" style="padding: 3px 5px 3px 3px; font-size: 12px; border: #666666 1px solid;">#thisRocks</td>
        </tr>
    </table>
</div>
<!--[if (mso) | (IE)]></td></tr></table><![endif]-->
 <!--[if ( gte mso 9) | (IE)]><table align="left"><tr><td align="center" valign="top" style="padding: 0 4px 5px 0;"><![endif]-->
<div style="display: inline-block; vertical-align: top; margin: 0 4px 5px 0;">
    <table bgcolor="#eaeaea" valign="top" align="center" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" border="0" style="border-collapse:collapse; background: #eaeaea;">
        <tr>
            <td align="center" bgcolor="#eaeaea" style="padding: 3px 5px 3px 3px; font-size: 12px; border: #666666 1px solid;">#yetanotherone</td>
        </tr>
    </table>
</div>
<!--[if (mso) | (IE)]></td></tr></table><![endif]-->
 <!--[if ( gte mso 9) | (IE)]><table align="left"><tr><td align="center" valign="top" style="padding: 0 4px 5px 0;"><![endif]-->
<div style="display: inline-block; vertical-align: top; margin: 0 4px 5px 0;">
    <table bgcolor="#eaeaea" valign="top" align="center" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" border="0" style="border-collapse:collapse; background: #eaeaea;">
        <tr>
            <td align="center" bgcolor="#eaeaea" style="padding: 3px 5px 3px 3px; font-size: 12px; border: #666666 1px solid;">#onemore</td>
        </tr>
    </table>
</div>
<!--[if (mso) | (IE)]></td></tr></table><![endif]-->
  <!--[if ( gte mso 9) | (IE)]><table align="left"><tr><td align="center" valign="top" style="padding: 0 4px 5px 0;"><![endif]-->
<div style="display: inline-block; vertical-align: top; margin: 0 4px 5px 0;">
    <table bgcolor="#eaeaea" valign="top" align="center" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" border="0" style="border-collapse:collapse; background: #eaeaea;">
        <tr>
            <td align="center" bgcolor="#eaeaea" style="padding: 3px 5px 3px 3px; font-size: 12px; border: #666666 1px solid;">#lastone</td>
        </tr>
    </table>
</div>
<!--[if (mso) | (IE)]></td></tr></table><![endif]-->
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Beautiful solution. Now all the tags can be looped using one block of code.

Answer (score 0):

Phillyoo, Outlook doesn't render 'display' style attributes. Even though the code above works, it will not render properly in Outlook.

Check out https://www.campaignmonitor.com/css/ - it's a good guide for designing emails.

You should be able to achieve your desired goal by using tables, rows, and td's. Use inline styling and apply 'align="left"' to your nested td's.

Example:

```html
  <table width="100%">
        <tr>
            <td>
                <table>
                    <tr>
                        <td align="left" style="">#hashtag</td>
                    </tr>
                </table>
                <table>
                    <tr>
                        <td align="left" style="">#hashtag</td>
                    </tr>
                </table>
            </td>
        </tr>
    </table>
```

You could also try having the TD tags in the same nested table and see how that works for you.

Best

Answer (score 0):

I actually Just had this exact same problem.  Here is a solid solution I came up with:

```
<tr>
  <td align="left">
    <table>
      <tr>
        <td valign="center" align="left" style="padding: 2px 2px 0 0;">
          <span style="padding: 2px 4px; border: 1px solid #dddddd; border-radius: 6px; -webkit-border-radius: 6px;">
            hashtag
          </span>
        </td>                             
      </tr>
    </table>
  </td>
</tr>
```